bmatrix* from mathtools results in huge column spacing when using [S]
I want to vertical align values inside a matrix by the decimal separator.
The usage of \begin{bmatrix*}[r] only gives pretty results if all numbers have the same length. If this is not the case, \begin{bmatrix*}[S] should be the choise. But when using S instead of r there is a huge spaching between the columns, that isn't there when using r.
Is there a way to achive the same spacing when using \begin{bmatrix*}[S] like I get in the case of \begin{bmatrix*}[r]? Do I have to define the spacing or the amount of digits somewhere?
An additional problem is: when using S, the matrix becomes too lage for the page, while it fits when using r.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\prescript{I}{R}{\mathbf{T}} =
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
0.999995410442 & 0.003030234948 & 0.000054086158 & -0.057119779289\\
-0.003030265914 & 0.999995231628 & 0.000583264627 & 0.000670913956\\
-0.000052318472 & -0.000583425805 & 0.999999821186 & -0.242041617632\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0\\
\end{bmatrix*}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\prescript{I}{R}{\mathbf{T}} =
\begin{bmatrix*}[S]
0.999995410442 & 0.003030234948 & 0.000054086158 & -0.057119779289\\
-0.003030265914 & 0.999995231628 & 0.000583264627 & 0.000670913956\\
-0.000052318472 & -0.000583425805 & 0.999999821186 & -0.242041617632\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0\\
\end{bmatrix*}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}



You've not given siunitx any info about the numbers, so the centring is based on equal size either side of the decimal marker ... you'll need to give a table-format to avoid that

The “naked” S column type uses a default format, but you can locally set it to fit your specific needs.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\sisetup{
  table-format=-1.12,
}
\prescript{I}{R}{\mathbf{T}} =
\begin{bmatrix*}[S]
0.999995410442 & 0.003030234948 & 0.000054086158 & -0.057119779289\\
-0.003030265914 & 0.999995231628 & 0.000583264627 & 0.000670913956\\
-0.000052318472 & -0.000583425805 & 0.999999821186 & -0.242041617632\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0\\
\end{bmatrix*}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\sisetup{
  round-precision=6,
  round-mode=places,
  table-format=-1.6,
}
\prescript{I}{R}{\mathbf{T}} =
\begin{bmatrix*}[S]
0.999995410442 & 0.003030234948 & 0.000054086158 & -0.057119779289\\
-0.003030265914 & 0.999995231628 & 0.000583264627 & 0.000670913956\\
-0.000052318472 & -0.000583425805 & 0.999999821186 & -0.242041617632\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0\\
\end{bmatrix*}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


However, I'd probably define my own environment based on bmatrix.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{numbmatrix}{O{}}
 {
  \left[ \hspace{-\arraycolsep}
  \sisetup{#1}
  \begin{array}{*{\value{MaxMatrixCols}}{S}}
 }
 {
  \end{array}
  \hspace{-\arraycolsep} \right]
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\prescript{I}{R}{\mathbf{T}} =
\begin{numbmatrix}[table-format=-1.12]
0.999995410442 & 0.003030234948 & 0.000054086158 & -0.057119779289\\
-0.003030265914 & 0.999995231628 & 0.000583264627 & 0.000670913956\\
-0.000052318472 & -0.000583425805 & 0.999999821186 & -0.242041617632\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0\\
\end{numbmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\prescript{I}{R}{\mathbf{T}} =
\begin{numbmatrix}[
  round-precision=6,
  round-mode=places,
  table-format=-1.6,
]
0.999995410442 & 0.003030234948 & 0.000054086158 & -0.057119779289\\
-0.003030265914 & 0.999995231628 & 0.000583264627 & 0.000670913956\\
-0.000052318472 & -0.000583425805 & 0.999999821186 & -0.242041617632\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0\\
\end{numbmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}

